# Run supervisord without root access

Tags: bash, supervisord

Hi I'm really new to writing scripts and I searched a lot but all that I've found is scripts with full access. I don't have access to the /etc. I'm working in a host in the cloud but I have limited access this is why all my attempts were unsuccessful.
So far I have this:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    prog="supervisord"
    prefix="/usr/local/"
    exec_prefix="${prefix}"
    prog_bin="${exec_prefix}/bin/supervisord -c /home/user/supervisor/supervisord.conf"
    PIDFILE="/var/run/$prog.pid"

    start()
    {
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    daemon $prog_bin --pidfile $PIDFILE
    [ -f $PIDFILE ] && success $"$prog startup" || failure $"$prog startup"
    echo
    }

    stop()
    {
    echo -n $"Shutting down $prog: "
    [ -f $PIDFILE ] && killproc $prog || success $"$prog shutdown"
    echo
    }

    case "$1" in

    start)
    start
    ;;

    stop)
     stop
    ;;

    status)
    status $prog
    ;;

    restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;

    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
    ;;

    esac
```

But I always get this error:

```
   Starting supervisord: script.sh: 27: script.sh: daemon: not found
   script.sh: 28: script.sh: failure: not found
```

Please help I have no idea what is going on ...

Comment: ServerFault questions pertain to server administration in a professional context. If you do not have access to `/etc`, then you are not an administrator of the system.

Comment: It seems that you have a misconfiguration in your `supervisor` config file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you got your example (`init.d`) script from something that uses the program `daemon` to daemonize other—non-daemon—programs, and you are missing that program.

I don't have `daemon` installed (Ubuntu 12.04), and you don't need it for `supervisord`. You can use `--pidfile=FILE` directly on `supervisord` itself an it will daemonize itself [unless directed otherwise](http://supervisord.org/running.html#running-supervisord).

You should check if you can write to `/var/run/supervisord.pid`, or otherwise specify a different, accessible, location.